# Autopopulated List Based off Yes/No Answer

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to have a column populated based off yes/no answers in another sheet.

To clarify further, I have a sheet named ***Declaration*** where there are 3 columns titled: (1) term, (2) definition, (3) in stock. I would like another sheet (named ***Data Collection***) to be populated based off the "yes" items selected as "in stock" via a data validation list in the ***Declaration*** Sheet.

What I would like to be automatically populated in the ***Data Collection*** sheet is the name of *only* the products selected as *in stock* in the Declaration sheet.

So;
Declaration sheet example:

- Shoes | worn on foot | in stock
- Bottoms | worn lower half of body | not in stock
- Tops | worn on top half of body | in stock

What is to appear in the Data Collection sheet in A1, A2, A3 etc.:

- Shoes
- Tops

If anyone has any pointers, that would be great! If you need any further clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Screen Shot. For better understanding I've created a Scenario on one sheet, you just placed in two different sheets.

**I've created two methods, one is with Yes/No other is without Yes/No.**

[image]

**NB:** Few things you must keep in mind.

1. While creating Sheet Declaration, use Data Validation for Column In-Stock, validate with 2 Values, In Stock & out Of Stock.
2. For  Yes/No method create a Check Box, change it's Caption to Yes, link a blank Cell with it as I did (Cell E470). Remember for each row a Check Box is required.
3. Then after in Data Collection Sheet in Term Column write this Formula.

=IF(Sheet1!G473="","Stock Not Updated",IF(AND(Sheet1!G473<>"",Sheet1!E470=TRUE),Sheet1!E473,Sheet1!G473))

4. If you don't like Yes/No metod, just type this Formula for In-Stock column.

=IF(G473="","Stock Not Updated",IF(G473="in stock",E473,G473))

**Note also**, in both the Formulas I've tested the Blank Cell, this situation may arise when the In-stock Column is still not updated (even Validation is applied).

Please Change the Data Range as your need.

**I've posted the Solution after is been tested by me.**